# Trying to render a large columnar grid within a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5

I have created a sort of GRID using uitableView. For that I have taken various labels for showing grid type line I am using line image. So by considering Grid my tableview is having around 88 columns.

My issue is when I scroll it down, I am getting jerky effect. Its performance s very poor. I am creating around 108 label and each row is having 88 labels and 86 image views.

What step do I need to follow to improve scrolling performance???

I was using clearColor for label background. But later on I have removed those background colors.

Comment: Are you saying that you have added 88 labels and 86 image view on EACH row of your table cell? This would mean that either you have 1px wide labels or you scroll in both the horizontal and vertical directions. Or are the cells incredibly tall?

Comment: I have added tableview on Scrollview. So On row I have 88 labels and 86 imageViews. label is having approx. 100p width and image view is having 2p width.

Comment: I get it. The 2px wide images are your cell separators. So you have an 8972px wide table cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having read your problem again, I am thinking you are scrolling horizontally and vertically with an incredibly wide tableview. If this is the case then you need to switch to UIScrollView and attach each item to this view. UIScrollView will only load the views that are visible and provide the kind of scroll performance you desire.

It will be important to avoid this:

```
// Using ARC, therefore no release on the UILabel
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24]; 
    CGSize size = [@"10000:10000" sizeWithFont:font];

    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(10000 * size.width, 10000 * size.height);

    for (int y = 0; y < 10000; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 10000; x++) {
            NSLog(@"Loading: %d, %d", x, y);
            UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x * size.width, y * size.height, size.width, size.height)];
            label.font = font;
            label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d", x, y];
            [_scrollView addSubview:label];
        }
    }
}
```

While this will eventually load it will take ages while it loads up all of these labels and it will consume a ton of memory. You want to lazy load this view just like a TableView. I will write up an example this evening.

Comment: but I am having min 30000 records, so it would be tedious to handle  and maintain all views if I use scrollview instead of tableview.

Comment: Here is the problem. A table view cell is essentially a view attached to a scrollview and each view can be unloaded from memory. If you attach everything to one table view cell it must load and unload the whole cell. You need to break it down by attaching each view in a loop, adjusting the x and y values as you go, to a UIScrollView. Essentially you need to roll your own table because UITableView was never meant to present columnar data.

Comment: Yes this can be done done but very time consuming for now... But really than you

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the table cell a reuse identifier. Otherwise, each time you create a completely new cell and consume more and more memory.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *const kReuseIdentifer = @"ReuseIdentifer";

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kReuseIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: @user1988 Are you doing network related activity on the main thread?
Are you using transparency in your cells? A table shouldn't have performance issues when scrolling. Without more detail you will need to use the Xcode tool Instruments to identify your problem.

Comment: @user1988 You mention UILabel had a custom background color. Did you define the cell in a XIB or did you define it programmatically?

Comment: Yes some of Labels were having transparency but later on I removed it and tried but still its not working smoothly. and no I am not doing any network related things.